# Querying for who worked on an item first and second

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Id (PK, int, not null)
ReviewedBy (nvarchar(255), not null)
ReviewDateTime(datetime, not null)
Decision_id (int, not null)
Item_id (FK, int, not null)
```

The business process with this table is that each `Item` (shown by `Item_id` foreign key) is to be worked on by 2 people.

How can I query this table to determine who (`ReviewedBy`) reviewed the item first and who reviewed it second.

I'm really struggling to figure this out because I neglected adding a `Type` column to my table that would determine which the user was acting as. :(

#### Edit

Given the following data

```
Id,ReviewedBy,ReviewedWhen,SomeOtherId,
16,111111,2011-12-14 22:06:54,1,
17,187935,2011-12-14 22:07:03,1,
18,187935,2011-12-14 22:07:18,2,
19,187935,2011-12-14 22:07:20,3,
20,111111,2011-12-14 22:07:23,2,
21,187935,2011-12-14 22:07:26,3,
22,123456,2011-12-14 22:27:50,4,
```

with schema

```
CREATE TABLE [Reviews] (
[Id] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
[ReviewedBy] NVARCHAR(6)  NOT NULL,
[ReviewedWhen] TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
[SomeOtherId] INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
```

Executing the following to get a list of people who did second reviews will return rows where there is only one review for `SomeOtherId`.

```
select t1.*
from Reviews as t1
  left outer join Reviews as t2
    on (t1.SomeOtherId = t2.SomeOtherId and t1.ReviewedWhen < t2.ReviewedWhen)
where t2.SomeOtherId is null;
```

#### Solution

```
-- First checks
select t1.ReviewedBy, count(t1.Id)
from Reviews as t1
  left outer join Reviews as t2
    on (t2.SomeOtherId = t1.SomeOtherId and t1.ReviewedWhen > t2.ReviewedWhen)
where          t2.SomeOtherID is null
group by t1.ReviewedBy;

-- Second checks
select t1.ReviewedBy, count(t1.Id)
from Reviews as t1
  left outer join Reviews as t2
    on (t2.SomeOtherId = t1.SomeOtherId and t1.ReviewedWhen < t2.ReviewedWhen)
where          t2.SomeOtherID is null
and  t1.Id not in (select Id from Reviews group by SomeOtherId having count(SomeOtherId) = 1)
group by t1.ReviewedBy;
```

Essentially, it was counting items where there was only one review as both a first and second check. All I had to do was ensure that when I'm counting second checks that I'm not including rows with only one review.

I thought I could achieve this in one query but guess not.

Comment: Do you know the Item_id?  If so, just select by the item_id and order by reviewdatetime.

Comment: I don't know the `Item_id`. I'm simply querying to find all rows where the `ReviewDateTime` is today.

Comment: ok so you want all the records regardless of the item_id, do you want one row for each item_id or are multiple ordered rows ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
t1.ReviewedBy FirstReviewer,
t2.ReviewedBy SecondReviewer
from
Table t1
left outer join Table t2 on t1.Item_Id = t2.Item_Id and t2.ReviewDateTime > t1.ReviewDateTime
```

If you want to only return rows that have been reviewed by two people, change the left outer join to an inner join.

If ReviewDateTime is never updated and Id is an identity column you can change the join to join on Id rather ReviewDateTime, which will be faster.

Comment: You are right that this solution assumes that the OP is enforcing the constraint stated in the question - "The business process with this table is that each Item (shown by Item_id foreign key) is to be worked on by 2 people."

Comment: Um, it looked like this query did the trick but it appears to be returning too much data. I've tried grouping by Item_id and doing a `min()` and `max()` however by doing that I am unable to retrieve the `ReviewedBy` column as it won't be part of an aggregate function.

Comment: It returned too much data because there are too many item records? If so, why not put a "where" constrainst on item_id range?

Comment: It appears to be double counting. I can't set a constraint on the `Item_id` range because I want query all reviews as it's only a few hundred. For example, an `Item_id` may only have one review.

Comment: Is every item worked on by at most two people? As mentioned by Magnus the query won't work otherwise.

Comment: Yes, 2 people max (this detail gets taken care of by the application). Creating a sample database (SQLite) it looks like the issue stems from if an item only has one review for the current day. In that case it gets counted twice.